# No puedo acceder a phpMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

He instalado Bitnami para instalar wordpress en local.
Las páginas que edito no se cargan en mi dominio. Desde wordpress no puedo cambiar la url contra la que quiero trabajar.
Supongo que debo configurar en phpMyAdmin, pero no consigo entrar. ¿El nombre de usuario no debería ser el mismo que para Bitnami? ¿No hay algo así como "he olvidado mi contraseña"?
Os agradezco de antemano

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para ver si es pertinente preguntar sobre el tema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si trabajas en local es normal que en tu dominio no se vean sino solamente en localhost/tu_carpeta_de_instalación/etc...

Dices:

> Desde wordpress no puedo cambiar la url contra la que quiero trabajar

No funciona así.
Desde Wordpress puedes definir la dirección de los enlaces y dónde esta alojada la página pero no puedes "trabajar remotamente" a menos que tengas un "wordpress remoto" al que estés accediendo.

Recuerda que lo has instalado en local y estas trabajando en tu propio ordenador, NO en el servidor de destino.

Dices:

> El nombre de usuario no debería ser el mismo que para Bitnami?

No: Aunque hayas elegido el mismo nombre de usuario, en una instalación tendrás una contraseña y en la otra puedes tener una diferente

Para restablecer contraseña accede a la página **wp-login.php** escribiendo esto justo al final de tu URL (poniendo primero una barra (/)).

Edito:
Para acceder a phpmyadmin teclea "localhost" en la barra de direcciones del navegador y en lo encuentras en la parte superior a la derecha de todo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]